# I am having trouble adding elements to a referenced vector of a map

Tags: dictionary, vector, reference, segmentation-fault, fault

EDIT: Forgot to mention that my programming language is C++, and my IDE is Qt Creator.

I don't understand why I am having trouble adding elements to a referenced vector of a map (i.e. sometimes it works and sometimes it fails).

For example:

```
class C_html4_tags {
     public:
       C_html4_tags();
       //.......

       typedef std::vector<S_html_attr_value> TYPE_attr_values;

    //.....
};

//...
C_html4_tags::C_html4_tags() {

//........
map<S_browser, TYPE_attr_values> attr_supported_attr_values_map;
S_browser dummy_browser; //a fake browser key for referencing a fully Html 4.01-compliant supported attr values list
dummy_browser.name = "Dummy";

//.....
TYPE_attr_values& attr_supported_attr_values = attr_supported_attr_values_map[dummy_browser];

//......
**attr_supported_attr_values = attr_supported_attr_values_map[dummy_browser];**

//...
**attr_supported_attr_values.clear();
  attr_supported_attr_values_map.clear();**

//......
**attr_supported_attr_values = attr_supported_attr_values_map[dummy_browser];**

//...
**attr_supported_attr_values.clear();
attr_supported_attr_values_map.clear();**

}
```

I do the bolded lines multiple times with a bunch of different attributes, with very little difference between them, without a problem until reaching this one attribute (a_tabindex_attr), in which the IDE doesn't report anything wrong when running it normally (except "The program has unexpectedly finished." However, when debugging it, it now reports:

> **Signal received**
>
> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating
>   System.
>
> Signal name :  SIGSEGV Signal meaning :  Segmentation fault

And the backtrace points to the attribute I mentioned above, on the line of code which does this:

```
attr_supported_attr_values.clear();
```

Now, after adding some debugging cout lines to the code, I learned that what's happening is, for some reason, even after doing:

```
attr_supported_attr_values.push_back(attr_value);
```

the vector object which is the returned mapped value of:

```
attr_supported_attr_values = attr_supported_attr_values_map[dummy_browser];
```

is not actually being changed when I push_back an S_html_attr_value object to the referenced vector. Now, I don't why that is, since I do pretty much the exact same thing in a bunch of other attributes' code before this one, without any problem, but for some reason now, on this one, it ain't adding the object to attr_supported_attr_values (which is a reference to the returned mapped value of 'dummy_browser'). And I know this for a fact, because I outputted the size of the internal mapped value object of the map (using an iterator for the map), and it was 0 after the call to push_back(). However, what is even more odd is, I ALSO outputted attr_supported_attr_values.size() after the call to push_back(), and that was 1! Now how could that be since they're both supposed to be the same object??

Note:

The full code of what I'm talking about is below (or at least the attribute code, minus the debugging statements...):

```
//a_tabindex_attr:
attr_desc = "Specifies the position of an <a> element in the\n"
            "tabbing order for the current document.\n"
            "The tabbing order defines the order in which\n"
            "elements will receive focus when navigated by\n"
            "the user via the keyboard. The tabbing order\n"
            "may include elements nested within other elements.\n"
            "Elements that may receive focus based on tabindex\n"
            "adhere to the following rules:\n\n"
            "1. Those elements that support this attribute and\n"
            "assign a positive value to it are navigated first.\n"
            "Navigation proceeds from the element with the\n"
            "lowest tabindex value to the element with the\n"
            "highest value. Values need not be sequential\n"
            "nor must they begin with any particular value.\n"
            "Elements that have identical tabindex values\n"
            "should be navigated in the order they appear\n"
            "in the character stream.\n"
            "2. Those elements that do not support this\n"
            "attribute or support it and assign it a value\n"
            "of \"0\" are navigated next. These elements are\n"
            "navigated in the order they appear in the\n"
            "character stream.\n"
            "3. Elements that are disabled do not participate\n"
            "in the tabbing order.";
attr_supported_attr_values = attr_supported_attr_values_map[dummy_browser];

attr_value_desc = "A number you specify for the tab index/order.\n"
                  "It must be a value between 0 and 32767.";
attr_value_content = "<i>number</i>";
attr_value = C_html4_attributes_obj.getAttrValue(attr_value_desc, attr_value_content,
                                                 attr_value_supported_browsers,
                                                 attr_value_required, attr_value_deprecated,
                                                 attr_value_notes, attr_value_tips);
attr_value.is_relative = true;
attr_supported_attr_values.push_back(attr_value);

try {
   N_init_class_members::initAttr(C_html4_attributes::attr_tabindex, a_tabindex_attr, attr_desc,
                                  attr_supported_browsers, attr_supported_attr_values_map, attr_required,
                                  attr_deprecated, attr_notes, attr_tips);
}

catch (const char* exc) {
     string exc_str = "Error! Call to N_init_class_members::initAttr() from\n"
                      "constructor of C_html4_tags class. That function\n"
                      "reported the following exception:\n\n";
     exc_str += exc;
     throw (exc_str.c_str()); //re-throw exception
}
a_tabindex_attr.is_standard_attr = true;
a_tabindex_attr.is_optional_attr = true;

//cleanup from attribute operations so we can begin working on the next attribute:
C_html4_attributes_obj.clear(); //wipes the slate clean for all the supported attributes' properties except content
attr_desc.clear();
attr_supported_attr_values.clear();
attr_supported_attr_values_map.clear();
attr_value_desc.clear();
attr_value_content.clear();
```

Comment: You might get more attention if you phrased your question in a more concise manner...